# Retrieve file URL when upload form is submitted

Tags: 7, forms, files

I have the following code in my form.

```php
function video_subtitles_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['video_subtitles_test/upload'] = array(
    'title' => 'Upload Subtitle', //page title
    'description' => 'Uploading subtitle for videos',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('video_upload_subtitles_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );

  return $items;
}

function video_upload_subtitles_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array('#attributes' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'));
  $form['video_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Name Of the video'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
  );

  $form['sub_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Upload video'),
    '#size' => 48,
    '#description' => t('Pick a video file to upload.'),
  );

  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );

  return $form;
}

function video_upload_subtitles_form_validate() {
  if (!file_check_upload('upload')) {
    form_set_error('upload', 'File missing for upload.');
  }
}

function video_upload_subtitles_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $video_name = $form_state['values']['video_name'];
  $file = file_save_upload('sub_file', array());
  print "<pre>";print_r($file);// no response here 
  drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
}
```

On the submission handler, it only returns the text field. I don't get anything from file upload field, when I use [`file_save_upload()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7).

This is the response which I get in Firebug. I tried uploading text and Excel files.

> [image: Firebug]

What I am trying to do is creating a block where users can upload a file; I then need to get to upload it to a CDN.

Comment: Have you looked at this comment in the file_save_upload API [discussion](https://api.drupal.org/comment/23883#comment-23883)?

Comment: `file_save_upload` returns _An object containing the file information if the upload succeeded, FALSE in the event of an error, or NULL if no file was uploaded._. So if you your result is `NULL`, it means no file was uploaded, and you should probably look into your server config. If it was `FALSE`, it means there was an error which you can find in your server logs or Drupal's watchdog (or both). 99 times out of 100 failures are due to permissions problems

Comment: this is the error stored in drupal log 

Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'H:\xampp\tmp\phpBBFD.tmp' to 'temporary://images.txt' in drupal_move_uploaded_file() (line 1607 of H:\xampp\htdocs\gemkt\trunk\includes\file.inc).

Answer (score 0):

found the solution [here](https://drupal.org/node/449292).I am not sure what is the core issue but below is the solution

This was the comment in the above link where I found solution.

> More than likely eveyone who is having a problem here has been
>   developing on their local computer, then are tryng to migrate their
>   system to a remote server. When you do this, you are probably moving
>   your setting for directory paths along as well.
>
> For example the temp path for your images is probably different than
>   the image temp path on your host system.
>
> I recommend this test in Drupal 6.14. goto /admin/settings/file-system
>
> and look at your temporary directory... if its glaring red, then try
>   renaming it to something like: /tmp. if that does not work, try
>   renaming to just tmp ( no forward slash)
>
> Next step to test this will be to upload an image or file. I tested it
>   by uploading a new logo. But remember, that if you do a FULL DB dump
>   from phpmyadmin from your local computer to the new host, you will
>   probably see this problem again.

For Drupal 7 guys I just went to admin/config/media/file-system , so basically find out where the file system is in your config area and I change the '/tmp' to 'tmp'.

After changing it was able to print the file object :)

```
stdClass Object ( [uid] => 1 [status] => 0 [filename] => 3-26-2014 12-15-54 PM.png [uri] => temporary://3-26-2014 12-15-54 PM.png [filemime] => image/png [filesize] => 30536 [source] => private_file [destination] => temporary://3-26-2014 12-15-54 PM.png [timestamp] => 1395828492 [type] => image [field_replacement] => stdClass Object ( [uid] => 1 [status] => 0 [filename] => 3-26-2014 12-15-54 PM.png [uri] => temporary://3-26-2014 12-15-54 PM.png [filemime] => image/png [filesize] => 30536 [source] => private_file [destination] => temporary://3-26-2014 12-15-54 PM.png [timestamp] => 1395828492 [type] => image ) [fid] => 3102 )
```

Hope it help someone.